# How can I upload a picture on an Android emulator using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to upload a picture to the server using the Android emulator but I get some errors which include:

1. FileNotFoundException on the server
2. Error on FileTransfer.upload
3. Error on FileTransfer.execute
4. IOException: Received error from server.
5. "http_status":500, "code":3

I have tried clearing the cache on my emulator, have used the web browser on the emulator to upload an image and that works. I have also set `options.chunkedMode = false;`
I am using Cordova 2.0.0 and running the emulator using Android 4.1.

Could anyone please help me with this or if anyone has ever experience the same errors please assist me.

P.S: The code is shown below:

```
function uploadPhoto() {
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=_img.substr(_img.lastIndexOf('/')+1);      
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

var params = new Object();
params.HCPracticeNumber = "11331";
params.ServiceDate = "12 Sep 2012";
params.AmountClaimed = "200";

options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(_img, "http://172.20.09.12/asd123", win, fail, options, true);
}
```

Comment: show some code so we can see what may be going wrong

Comment: @SimonMacDonald I have edited my post, please let me know if this info is sufficient.

Comment: Kinda looks like the url you are trying to talk to on the server does not exist.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald I changed the url to the following "http://172.18.80.103/asd123" but I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: `_img` is undefined as per your code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your server-side code, that you are looking for the word 'file' as it's specified in the code.  See what I quoted below:

```
options.fileKey="file";
```

For example in PHP server code:

```
$_FILES['file']['name']
```

If you use any other words beside 'file', you'll get the error.